# Querying the API via JavaScript / CORS (teamup.com calendar)

Tags: javascript, npm, discord.js, calendar

I am currently trying to figure out how to query the API of a calendar on teamup.com and retrieve data (events in the calendar) from it.

There's a code example on their website: [Querying the API via JavaScript / CORS](https://apidocs.teamup.com/#querying-the-api-via-javascript--cors)

I tried to make it work in Visual Studio, so I had to install XMLHttpRequest via npm and add a `require` code line:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

// Creates a CORS request in a cross-browser manner
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var apiKey = 'API_KEY'; //placeholder for api key
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari/IE10+.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Teamup-Token', apiKey);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // XDomainRequest for IE8/IE9.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        // XDomainRequest does not support querying HTTPS from HTTP pages
        if (window.location.protocol === 'http:') {
            url = url.replace('https://', 'http://');
        }
        if (-1 === ['GET', 'POST'].indexOf(method)) {
            alert('XDomainRequest only supports GET and POST methods');
            return;
        }
        if (-1 === url.indexOf('?')) {
            url += '?_teamup_token=' + apiKey;
        } else {
            url += '&_teamup_token=' + apiKey;
        }
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        // CORS not supported.
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}

// Sends the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest(url, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
    if (!xhr) {
        alert('CORS not supported');
        return;
    }

    // Response handlers.
    xhr.onload = function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.target.status < 400) {
            if (successCallback) successCallback(xhr.target);
        } else if (errorCallback) {
            errorCallback(xhr.target);
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (xhr) {
        if (errorCallback) {
            errorCallback(xhr.target);
        }
    };

    xhr.send();
}

// Send a GET request for all events in a date range
makeCorsRequest(
    'https://api.teamup.com/ks73ad7816e7a61b3a/events?startDate=2015-06-01&endDate=2015-06-05',
    function(xhr) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        alert('Successfully Received: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    function(xhr) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        alert('Request failed with code '+ xhr.status +': ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
);
```

When I try to run the program per node I get this terminal output:

```
PS C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\teamup-test> node team-up-test.js
C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\teamup-test\team-up-test.js:45
        if (xhr.target.status < 400) {
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\teamup-test\team-up-test.js:45:17)
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\teamup-test\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib\XMLHttpRequest.js:591:25)
    at setState (C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\teamup-test\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib\XMLHttpRequest.js:614:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\Documents\GitHub\teamup-test\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib\XMLHttpRequest.js:447:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

So it seems like the program cannot read `xhr.target.status`, but why?

Summarized: I want to fetch calendar event data from my calendar on team-up per JS and display that data on a discord bot.

I am wondering if I even do need CORS since it's only for browsers. Hoping someone could guide me into the right direction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code tutorial here: https://apidocs.teamup.com/#querying-the-api-via-javascript--cors is to be executed in the browser, in the **client**. I don't think it can be used in the **server**. Remember, Node.js is a back-end language, it runs on the server, not on the browser.

You can make an API call in Node.js with the code below, but you should study **Axios** later

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
    hostname: 'api.teamup.com',    
    path: '/ks73ad7816e7a61b3a/events?startDate=2015-06-01&endDate=2015-06-05',
    headers: {
        "Teamup-Token" : "API_KEY"
    },
  };

https.get(options, (resp) => {

  let data = '';    

  resp.on('data', (receivedDataBuffer) => {
    data += receivedDataBuffer;    
  });

  resp.on('end', () => {    
        let receivedDataAsJSON = JSON.parse(data);

        //do what you need with the json    
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually studied "got" a little bit, but couldnt find a workaround sadly. I'll check out Axios then.

And could you please help me with that variable receivedDataAsJSON: What exactly is in there and how do I read their data? I am assuming those are my calendar events right?

Comment: it will depend on how is the JSON object. you will use for example: receivedDataAsJSON.Name / receivedDataAsJSON.Person.Age

Comment: maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/02/a-beginners-guide-to-json-the-data-format-for-the-internet/?cb=1&_ga=2.135099698.287460510.1654346899-688059562.1649818555) can help you, if you find my answer helpful, i would really appreciate if you mark as accepted and up vote =D

Comment: ok thank you and how would you use Axios though?

Comment: Axios is a third-part library, it makes the API calls less verbose. But i believe you should study that library later on. You will get more value from studying the basics first, i guess the oficial tutorial is a good start: [https://nodejs.dev/learn](https://nodejs.dev/learn) you should watch videos on youtube also, search "node .js tutorial" or stuff like that in the google... Good luck!